# -webkit-transform scale: how to get the coordinates of a visible area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale, webkit-transform

I have an image which is displayed in a fixed div.

```
<div>
  <img src="path/to/image" id="map" />
</div>
```

I'm using the -webkit-transform property to scale and navigate to the scaled image (not other browsers required. just webkit). All the stuff is being done with javascript/jquery. The navigation works in any directions. The maximum scale zoom is 10.

E.g.:

```
<button id="up">zoom in and move up</button>

$('#up').on('click',function() {
    $('#map').css({'webkitTransform':'translateX('+SOME_VALUE+'px) translateY('+SOME_VALUE+'px) scale('+ SCALE +')'});
});
```

Everything works fine.

The difficulty is in a different place:

The image has a circle point on it. I know the coordinates of this point and its radius (e.g. X-100px,Y-100px,R-10px); These coordinates are related to the image.

### Question:

How can I determine whether this circle point is visible or not if the image is scaled?
How can I determine what area of the image is visible? 
How can I determine its *actual* coordinates in the resized state.
Please do not hesitate to take a look at the example image that shows the desired:

[image]

UPDATE:

Unfortunately, the solutions given below are not quite correct. By multiplying jquery value of the height() and the scale rate you won't get the accurate results.
I found the solution myself. 
There is the following javascript (not jquery) property:

[element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect)

This property reflects the real dimensions of the resized image and returns the real coordinates of an actual position. 
The usage with jquery is the following:

```
$('#some_element')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
```

I hope it will be useful for those guys who meet the problem in the future:)

Comment: If it answers your question, you should post it as an answer and link to where you found the solution (blog, documentation, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could get div size with `$("#yourDiv").height()` or `$("#yourDiv").width()`, and than get the image size and determinate her position to the div with `$('#yourImage').position().left` and `$('#yourImage').position().top`. With few of if statements you should find out where your image is positioned.

Comment: I've already tried that. It does not work, unfortunately. .width() && .height() always return the old values, not the resized ones.

Comment: then scale those values